# Set Checked Radio Button Using a JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to set the checked radio button using a JavaScript variable? I was hoping I could get the radio button by ID and update the checked radio.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
var shirtColor = "green";

document.getElementById(shirtColor); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Shirt Color:
<input type="radio" name="shirtColor" id="red" value="red" />
Red
<input type="radio" name="shirtColor" id="green" value="green" />
Green
<input type="radio" name="shirtColor" id="blue" value="blue" /> 
Blue</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just set its `checked` property to `true`:

```
document.getElementById(shirtColor).checked = true;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akkSY/

Comment: @user1822824 - You have to wait for the elements to be available. Put your `script` at the bottom of the `body` tag, after those elements are already on the page.

Answer (score 3):

It would look like that

```
btn = document.getElementById("itsID");
btn.checked = true;
```

Comment: Probably because you have to put shirtColor instead of itsID, 'itsID' was used as an example

Answer (score 2):

you can use jquery in this way

```
$("control_id").attr("checked",true);
```

**be sure that element is loaded before this jquery is executed.. to be safe you should always put scripts in the end of the page before `</body>` tag**